# The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object "SELECT * FROM funk"

Tags: vba, ms-access-2003

I want to write a very simple query and bind it to a listbox with VBA code but an error occures by running this piece of code:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM funk", dbOpenTable)
Me.List9.Recordset = rs
End Sub
```

the name of the databse is correct. Could you please inform me how can I solve this problem?

**Edit**

I've changed my code to

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM funk")
Me.List9.Recordset = rs
```

but it doesn't work too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for such complication:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
Me.List9.Rowsource = "SELECT * FROM TableName"
End Sub
```

However, it would be much better to say:

```
Me.List9.Rowsource = "SELECT ID,VisibleField FROM TableName"
```

You can the hide the ID field yet any selection in a simple select is equal to the ID when the Bound Column is 1.

You will need:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
'dbOpenDynaset is the default here, but it would not be the default for 
'a local table
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM funk",dbOpenDynaset)
Set Me.List9.Recordset = rs
```

Note Set on the last line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer remou, but I want to do this Job with Recordset.Is it Possible?Why I see this error?

Comment: That specific error is because you have `dbOpenTable` but you are not opening a table, after that, you will get an error when you try to set the listbox recordset. If you must do this, you will need an ADODB recordset, AFAIK.

Comment: It seems that you are missing Set, see above. You also need a Dynaset type, which is the default for queries and attached tables, but not for local tables : `db.OpenRecordset("Table1")`

Comment: You **do not** need an ADO recordset as I first thought.